# I get error 500 when I try to edit the theme editor wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, themes, hook

i want to edit theme from theme editor page in wordpress
i taked error :
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in gillion\wp-includes\class-wp-theme.php on line 1401

however when i changed theme This problem is solved
code line 1401 class-wp-theme.php

```
$exclusions = (array) apply_filters( 'theme_scandir_exclusions', array( 'CVS', 'node_modules', 'vendor', 'bower_components' ) );

        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            if ( '.' === $result[0] || in_array( $result, $exclusions, true ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( is_dir( $path . '/' . $result ) ) {
                if ( ! $depth ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $found = self::scandir( $path . '/' . $result, $extensions, $depth - 1, $relative_path . $result );
                $files = array_merge_recursive( $files, $found );
            } elseif ( ! $extensions || preg_match( '~\.(' . $_extensions . ')$~', $result ) ) {
                $files[ $relative_path . $result ] = $path . '/' . $result;
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }
```

i don't see any error syntax

The things I did:
check file .htaccess
increase memory php
disable plugin
change theme that problem was solved

Comment: increase `max_execution_time`. read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-execution-time-taken-by-a-php-script/#:~:text=One%20important%20aspect%20of%20PHP,between%2030%20to%2060%20seconds.

Comment: @Vel If 300 seconds is not enough to display a theme customizer, there is something terribly wrong with the theme/child-theme and increasing `max_execution_time` is not going to solve it. Unless Elyas is trying to import some demo content with thousands of vars, couple of seconds for script execution should be perfectly enough.